# Gradle compiles java files in activemq-all-5.9.0 dependency jar during build

Tags: gradle, war

I recently included ActiveMQ 5.9.0 in my web application built using Gradle.

```
compile "org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:5.9.0"
```

The issue is that, since **activemq-all-5.9.0.jar** comes with both class files and source java files in it, when I build a war file using the below command, Gradle tries to compile the java files in activemq jar file and includes them in the war.

```
gradle clean war
```

During deployment, my app fails to start because of those compile activemq classes. Removing them from /WEB-INF/classes manually gets the app to working. I'm looking for automated way to exclude these java classes from making into my war file. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the default behavior of the Java compiler. Explicitly setting the source path to "nothing" should solve the problem:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-sourcepath", "''"]
}
```

As this question has been asked before, you should also be able to find existing answers on Stack Overflow or the [Gradle Forums](http://forums.gradle.org).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried your suggestion but I'm afraid the issue still persists. I did check gradle forum and found similar answers, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm afraid I'm kind of new to gradle builds. `
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.compilerArgs += ["-sourcepath", "''"]}
//compileJava.options.compilerArgs = ["-implicit:none"]
repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:5.9.0" ...
}`

Comment: You suggestion did work. From Gradle forums, I also found another way to do the same: compileJava.options.compilerArgs = ["-implicit:none"]

Answer (score 0):

```
javadoc  {
    options.addStringOption("sourcepath", "")
}
```

per [this disscussion on the gradle forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/javadoc_generation_failed_with_vaadin_dependency) fixed my issues with the javadoc task issuing the same error for a different third party jar.